# purchases.products.get returns error 400 always

Tags: android, google-play

Whatever I do

`GET https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/name.vporton.local_shops/purchases/products/credits_x1/tokens/GPA.3310-1432-5240-51581` (with an appropriate access token)

returns

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Value",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can query it at [this link](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get?apix_params=%7B%22packageName%22%3A%22name.vporton.local_shops%22%2C%22productId%22%3A%22credits_x1%22%2C%22token%22%3A%22GPA.3310-1432-5240-51581%22%7D).

I spent several days trying to make it work, no result.

I tried:

- linking Google Play Console to Google Developer Console
- editing permissions in both Google Play Console and Google Developer Console

Help! It is a stopper of my project.

Comment: I even wrote to Google and they... didn't reply.

Comment: @tukan What do you speak about? I don't use Java in this project at all!

Comment: @tukan You see in the answer that I used JSON API directly (and it does not work)

Comment: I see, well I thought you are getting JSON reply into java client.  I'll delete my comments

Comment: @tukan Don't delete all your comments. You pointed a related question URL. Please post it again with a note that that answer does NOT solve my problem (in order for somebody not to mark my question duplicate).

Comment: Ok, here is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453488/bad-request-invalid-value-when-trying-to-retrieve-in-app-purchase-info-using-t. You need to add details, how you send a request.  If you check the link you can see they get the reply also in JSON.

Comment: @tukan As I mention in the questions, I send request using GET (e.g. with Curl).

Comment: I tried testing in production mode with a real credit card payment. The same result. Moreover, I don't see the product purchase in financial reports at Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I used `productID` in place of purchase token.

I corrected my Flutter code from:

```dart
        body: "purchaseToken=${purchaseDetails.purchaseID}&"
            "productId=${purchaseDetails.productID}&"
            "appGuid=$guid");
```

to

```dart
        body: "purchaseToken=${purchaseDetails.verificationData.serverVerificationData}&"
            "productId=${purchaseDetails.productID}&"
            "appGuid=$guid");
```

and now this error does not appear anymore.